# How to get the min of a list with multiple dimensions?

Tags: r, list

I'm trying to avoid loops, but not sure how to do this:

Let's say I have the following:

```
theList <- list()
theList[[1]] <- list(foo = "1", bar = "10")
theList[[2]] <- list(bar = "10", foo = "4")
theList[[3]] <- list(foo = "-1", bar = "10")
```

How can I call a function such that I would get returned the minimum value for foo?

```
minValue(theList$foo)
```

or something like it... would return -1.

Comment: Why you are creating 'character' elements for numeric vectors? One option is `min(as.numeric(unlist(lapply(theList, function(x) x[names(x)=='foo']))))` or `unlist` the whole list and get the `min`. i.e `v1 <- unlist(theList);min(as.numeric(v1[names(v1)=='foo']))`

Comment: That's it.  Can you answer below so I can check your answer as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
v1 <- unlist(theList)
min(as.numeric(v1[names(v1)=='foo']))
#[1] -1
```